# Numpy genfromtxt memory leakage

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks

How can I fix this problem?

I'm writing a program that constantly loads a data file and parse it.
In that program, I use `numpy.genfromtxt()` to read the file and create an float array.

It works but a few days later, it turns to occupies several GB of memory.

Garbage collection tells unreachable memory leakage "<numpy.lib._iotools.LineSplitter object at 0x0000021DB9C3FC20>, <bound method LineSplitter._delimited_splitter of <numpy.lib._iotools.LineSplitter object at 0x0000021DB9C3FC20>"s found (and they increases as much as it repeats).

The file is `.csv`, contains string at first row but I use `skip_row`.

```
threadda = confu.ThreadPoolExecutor()
pooller = confu.ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

class AAA():
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        return
    # state some class variables
    class BBB():
        
        def __init__(self,arguments):
            self.arguments = arguments
            
        def Data_Collection(self):
            
            raw_ar=np.genfromtxt(self.file_to_read,delimiter=","skip_header=2,skip_footer=2,\
            usecols=(self.arguments),loose=True,dtype=np.float64,filling_values=1).T
            
            ar1=(float(raw_ar.copy()[0][0]),float(raw_ar.copy()[0][-1]))
            
            d_df=np.delete(arr=raw_ar,obj=0,axis=0)
            
            kata = d_df.shape
            ddf=[]
            dtf=[]
            
            [ ddf.append(d_df[i,:])  if (i%2 == 0) else  
            dtf.append(d_df[i,:])  if (i%2 == 1) else 0.0
            for i in range(0,kata[0]) ]
                
            tpl=(np.vstack(ddf,dtype=np.float64),np.vstack(dtf,dtype=np.float64))
            
            return (ar1,tpl)
            
        def Rendering(self,flags = True):
            array1,array2=self.Data_Collection()
            # calculation and plotting
            return

    @classmethod
    async def StandingBy(cls):
        while True:
            try:
                heart = AAA.Spine(cls.arguments)
                childp = await asyncio.wrap_future(pooller.submit(heart.Rendering,True, ))
                del childp
                del heart

            except OSError as err:
                # error handlings
            await asyncio.sleep(some)
    @classmethod
    async def loop_wrapper(cls):
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tkg:
            tkg.create_task(cls.StandingBy())
            tkg.create_task(cls.Communicate()) # Other tasks
        return
    
    @classmethod
    def mains(cls):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        # ...
        global threadda
        with threadda as thre:
            thre.submit(asyncio.run,cls.loop_wrapper())
            root.mainloop()

def main():
    AAA().mains()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mul.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Comment: Memory leakage in Python is usually an issue with objects still being referenced and therefore never garbage collected. It is probably not an issue with just using genfromtxt() several times but rather what you do with those numpy arrays. Can you post your full code?

Comment: Thank you for answering.Entire code is too long to post so the stem of the program is like below,

Comment: We don't need (or want) the whole code, but we do need a better idea of what you are doing, with a focus on the use of `genfromtxt`, its immediate result, and why you think it's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry I'm not familiar with this site,so it takes me some times to put my code.I editted my questionarie.

Comment: I though it was an issue with processpool, but deleting and await results didn't work.

Comment: Can you post more about the `Rendering()` function? As this is the function that keeps working with the data from `Data_Collection()` and may keep references to that data for each call.

Comment: Sure. Rendering() function calculates the recieved arrays with sort of functions like numpy.nanmean(), numpy.trapz(), scipy.curve_fit() ... and calls another function to draw a figure with matplotlib.pyplot.draw() and .pause(). I suspected they do something wrong and tried to alter .draw() .pause()  to .show() but it didn't work. I also tested pyplot.clf() and pyplot.cla().

Comment: What is `self.file_to_read`/  A string file name, or a file that you keep open?  If `genfromtxt` is opening and closing tihs file each time it's called, I would expect any sort of 'leak'.  It just opens the file, reads it line by line, parses, closes the file, and returns an array.  Of course your async threading potentially makes things a lot more complicated - and hard to reproduce and test outselves.

Comment: That paragraph starting `Garbage collection tells ...` is hard to follow.  It's not formatted right, and hard to tell what exactly is the source.

Comment: `self.file_to_read` is the file path to parse, one of the self.argements. I forgot to edit. As for garbage collection, I tried to work out what causes memory leakage by means of adding `gc.DEBUG_LEAK` and `gc.collect()` into while loop.

Comment: Just now, i realized the problem was the matter of scopes of walrus operator at if-passage in setting `cls.arguements`. I'm afraid i omitted that sentences from my questionarie (because I didn't think of its concerning). Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The list comprehension sfarting witb `[ ddf.append(d_df[i,:])...` is ugly even if it isn't problematic.  `append` changes the list, but returns `None`.  So the comprehension returns a list of `None` which you rightly ignore.  A regular for loop would be clearer, and no slower.

Comment: Thank you for your advises. I'll take them into account.